# Set Parent field to Identity field within Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as such

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog](
 [RID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ParentRID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ServerName] [varchar](100) NULL,
```

When i do the INSERT i want the ParentRID field to be the same as the RID initially.  I'd rather not do a separate UPDATE statement after the insert.  A DEFAULT will not work in this context.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Trigger for the AFTER INSERT event.

Comment: If you could pre-determine the `RID` value before the insert, you could `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.EventLog ON`, insert a row, then `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.EventLog OFF`.  You'd need `ALTER` permission on the table, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it is possible to do it in insert. Use a following trigger instead -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_yourid 
ON dbo.yourtablename 
after INSERT 
AS 
    UPDATE dbo.yourtablename                      
    SET    dbo.yourtablename.secondId = a.id -- Set the Parent ID to the value of Identity column
    FROM   dbo.yourtablename b 
           JOIN inserted a 
             ON a.id = b.id
```